# ThreadPoolExecutor never run exceeding poolsize

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

whatever I set the size of pool, the run results seems to not exceed the pool size.For example:

```
 BlockingQueue<Runnable>  queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
 ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8, 15, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS, queue);
 executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                }
            });
```

when I set 8, the first 8 results will synchronize. But the following only run one by one. 
what's wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

It says:

> #### Queuing
>
> Any BlockingQueue may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks. The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:
>
> If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
> If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
> If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.
>
> [...]
>
> Unbounded queues. Using an unbounded queue (for example a LinkedBlockingQueue without a predefined capacity) will cause new tasks to wait in the queue when all corePoolSize threads are busy. Thus, no more than corePoolSize threads will ever be created.

Comment: thank you:) I got it. So, I got this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435903/specifying-threadpoolexecutor-problem